# ASP.NET Panel subclass not appearing correctly in the Designer

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, custom-controls, panel

I have subclassed the ASP.NET Panel control to customise the rendering of the GroupingText.  However, while it appears fine in the final output, it is not appearing correctly in the designer.

A sample of what I am doing follows:

Is there anything else I need to do to make it appear correctly in the designer?

```
Imports System.Web.UI

Public Class CustomPanel
    Inherits Panel

    Public Overrides Sub RenderBeginTag(ByVal writer As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)
        Me.AddAttributesToRender(writer)
        Dim tagKey As HtmlTextWriterTag = Me.TagKey
        If (tagKey <> HtmlTextWriterTag.Unknown) Then
            writer.RenderBeginTag(tagKey)
        Else
            writer.RenderBeginTag(Me.TagName)
        End If
        Dim groupingText As String = Me.GroupingText
        If ((groupingText.Length <> 0) AndAlso Not TypeOf writer Is Html32TextWriter) Then
            writer.AddAttribute("class", "heading")
            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div)
            writer.Write(groupingText)
            writer.RenderEndTag()
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to take a tour through the MSDN posting about ["Adding Design Time Support to ASP.Net controls"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478960.aspx)

Just to let you know as well: creating custom server controls with robust design time support is not a trivial thing. If you can get away with using a UserControl, or dealing with the lack of design time support you are better off.

More often than not, this is an exercise that is better left to [people who do this for a living](http://www.google.com/sponsoredlinks?q=asp.net+controls&hl=en&rlz=1C1CHNP_enUS320US320&um=1&ie=UTF-8).